# bash: script to identify specific alias causing a bug

Tags: bash, shell, alias, archlinux

*[Arch Linux v5.0.7 with GNU bash 5.0.3]*

Some `.bashrc` aliases seem to conflict with a `bash` shell-scripts provided by `pyenv` and `pyenv-virtualenvwrapper`.
I tracked down the problem running the script, using `set -x` and with all aliases enabled, and saw finally that the script exits gracefully with exit code is 0 only when aliases are disabled with `unalias -a`. So this has to do with aliases... but which one ?

To try to automate that,  I wrote the shell-script below:

- It un-aliases one alias at a time, reading iteratively from the complete list of aliases,
- It tests the conflicting shell script `test.sh` against that leave-one-out alias configuration, and prints something in case an error is detected,
- It undoes the previous un-aliasing,
- It goes on to un-aliasing the next alias.

But the two built-ins `alias` and `unalias` do not fare well in the script `cac.sh` below:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
[ -e aliases.txt ] && rm -f aliases.txt
alias | sed 's/alias //' | cut -d "=" -f1 > aliases.txt
printf "File aliases.txt created with %d lines.\n" \
        "$(wc -l < <(\cat aliases.txt))"
IFS=" "
n=0
while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    n=$((n+1))
    aliasedAs=$( alias "$line" | sed 's/alias //' )
    printf "Line %2d: %s\n" "$n" "$aliasedAs" 
    unalias "$line"
    [ -z $(eval "$*" 1> /dev/null) ] \   # check output to stderr only
         && printf "********** Look up: %s\n" "$line"
    eval "${aliasedAs}"
done < <(tail aliases.txt)  # use tail + proc substitution for testing only
```

Use the script like so: `$ cac.sh test.sh [optional arguments to test.sh]`  Any `test.sh` will do. It just needs to return some non-empty string to stderr.

The first anomaly is that the file `aliases.txt` is empty as if the `alias` builtin was not accessible from within the script. If I start the script from its 3rd line, using an already populated `aliases.txt` file, the script fails at the second line within the while block, again as if `alias` could not be called from within the script.   *Any suggestions appreciated.*

**Note:** The one liner below works in console:

```
$ n=0;while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do n=$((n+1)); printf "alias %d : %s\n" "$n" "$(alias "$line" | sed 's/alias //')"; done < aliases.txt
```

Comment: `unalias -a suppresses the error` - what error? How do you call it? Are you sure? You seem to be explaining how to solve an alias conflict - that's XY problem. `.bashrc aliases seem to conflict with` - how did you detect that? `alias` is only accessible from within an interactive shell. You could `source` your script from an interactive console. Or call `bash --init-file` or similar.

Comment: Instead of parsing the output of `alias`, you can access the `BASH_ALIASES` shell variable (requires probably at least Bash 4.0). Also, as @KamilCuk points out, aliases are by default disabled in non-interactive shells, but you can set the `expand_aliases` shell options to enable them.

Comment: Have you seen the `BASH_ALIASES` associative array?

Comment: What is `[ -z $(eval "$*" 1> /dev/null) ]` intended to do? Since `1>/dev/null` is exactly identical to `>/dev/null`, stdout will always be an empty string, and because you don't use quotes, that means your test becomes `[ -z ]`, not `[ -z "" ]`. `[ -z ]` is the same as `[ -n "-z" ]`, which... okay, it's always true, but it's true for a very nonintuitive reason.

Comment: ...moreover, `[ -z $(whatever) ]`, if `whatever` *could* emit output, would run the risk of being wrong if that output is non-empty but word-splits into more than exactly one word. Consider `whatever() { echo "1 -o 0 -eq 0"; }` -- you'd need more quotes, as in `[ -z "$(whatever)" ]`, or to use `[[` instead of `[`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: What I want is to grab all arguments to `cac.sh` (in my use case: `"$(pyenv init -i)"; workon py2.7sphinx` and test for whether stderr receives anything (just stderr,not stdout). If it receives nothing `[ -z $(whatever) ]`  should evaluate to true...

Comment: Once again, though, `1>/dev/null` means that `whatever`'s output will **always** be empty. And because it's not quoted, it becomes `[ -z ]`, not `[ -z "" ]`. Those are both true statements, but they're true for very different reasons, and the first one is a lot more fragile (as I described above). Consider running `set -x` to enable logging, and looking at the expansion results.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I may be missing something. Normally I would use  `"$( )"` with double quotes, but I don't care about word splitting here. I only care about whether I get any error or nothing. Bad form ? If I get word splitting (and I most probably will) is it hurting me ? --- Just writing this I suppose it could if a specailly crafted error message was to spell something like `blah -o 1 -eq 1`.  Is it yr line of thinking ?

Comment: Even without that, if word splitting and glob expansion results in something that isn't valid `test` syntax, you'll get an error message to stderr that doesn't necessarily make sense to your end user. (Moreover, let's say your output *is* something that can be parsed as a glob -- suddenly, your shell's behavior depends on `nullglob`, `failglob`, etc, making the script less predictable).

Comment: BTW, the comment added to the `[ -z $(eval "$*" 1> /dev/null) ]` line I think makes it a little more clear where we're reading it differently. Keep in mind that `$(...)` doesn't capture stderr at all, but just passes it through to the calling process, so `[ ]` isn't checking whether there's stderr -- you'd need to make it something like `[ -z "$(... 2>&1 >/dev/null)" ]` to do that, making stderr point to the original stdout before redirecting stdout to /dev/null.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I thought that output redirection was specified from right to left. As shown does not yours mean: first, redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null`, second, redirect `stderr` to `stdout` which would effectively only display `stderr`. Your phrasing of redirection precedence seems to imply that **nothing** is displayed, ever.

Comment: They're performed left-to-right; see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection#multiple_redirections and/or [BashFAQ #55](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generally advise against implementing this as an external script at all -- it makes much more sense as a function that can be evaluated directly in your interactive shell (which is, after all, where all the potentially-involved aliases are defined).

```
print_result() {
  local prior_retval=$? label=$1
  if (( prior_retval == 0 )); then
    printf '%-30s - %s\n' "$label" WORKS >&2
  else
    printf '%-30s - %s\n' "$label" BROKEN >&2
  fi
}
test_without_each_alias() {
  [ "$#" = 1 ] || { echo "Usage: test_without_each_alias 'code here'" >&2; return 1; }
  local alias
  (eval "$1"); print_result "Unchanged aliases"
  for alias in "${!BASH_ALIASES[@]}"; do
    (unalias "$alias" && eval "$1"); print_result "Without $alias"
  done
}
```

Consider the following:

```
rm_in_home_only() { [[ $1 = /home/* ]] || return 1; rm -- "$@"; }
alias rm=rm_in_home_only  # alias actually causing our bug
alias red_herring=true    # another alias that's harmless

test_without_each_alias 'touch /tmp/foobar; rm /tmp/foobar; [[ ! -e /tmp/foobar ]]'
```

...which emits something like:

```
Unchanged aliases              - BROKEN
Without rm                     - WORKS
Without red_herring            - BROKEN
```

---

Note that if the code you pass executes a function, you'll want to be sure that the function is *defined* inside the `eval`'d code; since aliases are parser behavior, they take place when functions are *defined*, not when functions are *run*.

Answer (score 0):

@Kamil_Cuk, @Benjamin_W and @cdarke all pointed to the fact that a noninteractive shell (as that spawned from a `bash` script) does not have access to aliases.

@CharlesDuffy pointed to probable word splitting and glob expansion resulting in something that could be invalid test syntax in the  original `[ -z $(eval "$*" 1> /dev/null) ]` block above, or worse yet in the possibility of `$(eval "$*" 1> /dev/null)` being parsed as a glob resulting in unpredictable script behavior. Block corrected to: `[ -z "$(eval "$*" 1> /dev/null)" ]`.

Making the shell spawned by `cac.sh` interactive, with `#! /usr/bin/bash -i`. make the two built-ins `alias` and `unalias` returned non-null result when invoked, and `BASH_ALIASES[@]` became accessible from within the script.

```
#! /usr/bin/bash -i
[ -e aliases.txt ] && rm -f aliases.txt
alias | sed 's/alias //' | cut -d "=" -f1 > aliases.txt
printf "File aliases.txt created with %d lines.\n" \
        "$(wc -l < <(\cat aliases.txt))"
IFS=" "

while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    aliasedAs=$( alias "$line" | sed 's/alias //' )
    unalias "$line"
    [ -z "$(eval "$*" 2>&1 1>/dev/null)" ] \   # check output to stderr only
         && printf "********** Look up: %s\n" "$line"
    eval "${aliasedAs}"
done < aliases.txt
```

**Warning:** testing `test.sh` resorts to the `eval` built-in.  [Arbitrary code](https://medium.com/dot-debug/the-perils-of-bash-eval-cc5f9e309cae) can be executed on your system if `test.sh` and optional arguments do not come from a trusted source.

Comment: Honestly, I'm a little unclear on what you're trying to accomplish with the `eval` at all -- the usual (more reliable) way to run a precise list of arguments as a simple command is `"$@"`; if you want to *prepare* a string to be `eval`-safe, that would instead be something like `printf -v cmd_q '%q ' "$@"`, after which `eval "$cmd_q"` behaves identically to the above.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I intended just that with `IFS=' '` and the use of `"$*"`rather than "$@" so any argument to `cac.sh` would be prepared for `eval` with exactly one separation space between each word... Again, bad form ?   Incidentally I knew about `%q` to prepare for reuse of `printf` output as input, but did not know about the `printf -v <ouput_variable> ...` syntax. Tx.

Comment: The `$*` approach conflates `someprogram "two words"` with `someprogram "two" "words"`; both evaluate to the same result. I'd want to take a closer look at the script's underlying intent to speak to what would constitute a saner implementation.